# Postgres connections are becoming zero in DB pool after hikari maxLifetime?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

My Springboot application developed with **`version 2.1.5`**, when running it, its leaving the db connections in DB pool but after hikari max-lifetime all the connections that were created are elapsing. Any further `REST request` is not creating new connection and ending up with the error "**Unable to connect JDBC**"

What could be the problem and how can i overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you may suffer from a DB connection leak. HikariCP won't close connection in use despite the `maxLifetime` property:

> An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed.

You need to find out if your connections are leaking. For starters you could use another HikariCP property: `leakDetectionThreshold`:

> This property controls the amount of time that a connection can be out of the pool before a message is logged indicating a possible connection leak. A value of 0 means leak detection is disabled. Lowest acceptable value for enabling leak detection is 2000 (2 seconds). Default: 0